# chartjs 4.2.1 chartjs-plugins-datalabels labels outside pie chart

Tags: chart.js, bootstrap-5

I am trying to show labels outside segments on a chart js (4.2.1) pie chart using chartjs-plugins-datalabels but the labels are being clipped.

Is there a way to ensure the pie chart leaves enough room for the labels to be drawn fully?

Here are my chart options:

```
{
     animation: false,
     responsive: true,
     // maintainAspectRatio: false, // if false, labels are clipped further
     plugins: {
         title: {
             ...
         },
         datalabels: {
             anchor: 'end',
             align: 'end',
             font: {
                 size: 14
             },
             formatter: function (value, context) {
                 ...
             }
         },
         legend: {
             display: false
         }
     }
 }
```

Rendered html:

```
<div class="card h-100">
        <div class="card-header">Debts</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="container-fluid h-100">
                <div class="row h-100">
                    <div class="col">
                        <canvas height="363" width="363" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 363px; width: 363px;"></canvas>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <canvas height="363" width="363" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 363px; width: 363px;"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the result. Only one label is fully unclipped
[image: Result]

Comment: This post answered my question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50214709/chart-js-data-labels-getting-cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50214709/chart-js-data-labels-getting-cut)