# Datalabels cut off in Chart.js with React

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, chart.js

Sorry for poor English, its my second language.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I am currently using Next.js 14, MUI, Chart.js now.
My last dataset's label showing on the line chart is cutted off. I have added `offset: true` but it seems more space needed to display the whole label. How do I fix this chart to make it always showing the complete label?
This is my current code.

```
"use client";
import React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from "chart.js";
import ChartDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  ChartDataLabels
);

const Item = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? "#1A2027" : "#fff",
  ...theme.typography.body2,
  padding: theme.spacing(4),
  textAlign: "center",
  color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  height: "400px"
  width: "100%",
}));

const data = {
  labels: [
    "2022-09-05",
    "2022-10-26",
    "2023-03-12",
    "2023-06-30",
    "2023-07-29",
    "2023-08-18",
    "2023-10-21",
  ],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Level",
      data: [280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286],
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
      borderColor: "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.5)",
    },
  ],
};

const options = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    datalabels: {
      color: "#555",
      anchor: "end",
      align: "top",
      font: {
        size: 16,
      },
      formatter: (value, context) => {
        return context.chart.data.datasets[context.datasetIndex].data[
          context.dataIndex
        ];
      },
    },
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      offset: true,
      ticks: {
        font: {
          size: 18,
        },
      },
    },
    y: {
      offset: true,
      display: false,
      beginAtZero: false,
    },
  },
};

export default function HistoryTab() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
        <Stack spacing={2}>
          <Item>none</Item>
          <Item>
            <Typography
              variant="h6"
              sx={{ textAlign: "left", color: "primary", fontWeight: "bold" }}
            >
              history
            </Typography>
            <Box>
              <Line data={data} options={options} height={300} />
            </Box>
          </Item>
          <Item>none</Item>
        </Stack>
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: The standard solution is to set  [`options.layout.padding`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html#layout) for the whole chart, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50418891/16466946). If the space needed is not known beforehand, one can compute the overflow of the datalabels after the first rendering, and  use it immediately to [`update`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html#updating-options)  the chart.